# When behavioral simulation of RTL works but synthesis/implimentation do not

Tags: vhdl, verilog, xilinx, debugging, vivado

I wrote a UART receiver similar to [Nandland's](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/module-uart-serial-port-rs232.html) example.

To verify that I am receiving and processing data (coming from my PC through Putty), I wrote a design that would correspond certain LEDs to certain keyboard letters based on their ASCII character.

When I simulate the design, it works as intended.

*Problem*: **When I synthesize and then implement the design, no timing report shows up which leads me to believe Vivado is not creating a clock (or isn't connecting it).** *Why does the elaborated design show expected connectivity while the synthesized and implemented design do not?*

### Elaborated schematic:

[image]

To clarify, the design is supposed to store the data byte from the PC in a flip flop before going to 3 different LEDs on the board (Arty S7).

### Synthesized schematic:

[image]

### Implimentation schematic (literally):

[image]

And yes, I've used the same xdc file to make simple designs like a flashing LED to verify my constraint naming of the clock is correct (which is obviously taken from the manufacturer's github). I would post my code but that seems irrelevant since the tools are not even creating a gate level version of my code (regardless of whether it's correctly for my goal).

**EDIT**: here is the elaborated schematic of the UART

[image]

Comment: Can you show the elaborated schematic of the UART itself? It is possible that the UART itself mistakenly outputs a 0 unconditionally, and is optimized away in synthesis

Comment: Just added  the photo. My eyes don't see it going to zero...

Comment: Read the synthesis report file, carefully noting any warnings that may relate to teh UART being deleted.

Comment: Check DRC report.

Comment: It does show in the Synthesis log that "Sequential element (inst_UART_RX/FSM_sequential_state_reg[1]) is unused and will be removed from module Test. WARNING: [Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (inst_UART_RX/FSM_sequential_state_reg[0]) is unused and will be removed from module Test."  "Test" is the name of my top module

Comment: So from looking at what "state_reg" is on the schematic, I can click on "source" which takes me to the state register of the FSM used in the UART. So for some reason the FSM of the UART isn't even being used. Would this mean it has no input, drives no output or has an internal issues?

Comment: Means your code has problems.

Comment: that's what appears to be the case... It's difficult to find considering behavioral simulation runs fine and all values are initialized that "determine" other values so I'm not sure why it thinks the FSM of the UART isn't needed

Comment: Yeah, I found the coding problem.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the resolution in my code and decided I'd leave it here as a warning to anyone who gets good behavioral simulation results (**using VHDL**) but incorrect synthesis and implimentation results.

It all has to do with VHDL's *wonderful* `integer range` command in which you can specify the ***decimal size*** of the integer. *Behavioral simulation ignores this command and will allow that integer to be larger than the range you gave it but synthesis and implimentation do not.*

---

My example:

```
signal byte_index : integer range 0 to 7 := 0;
```

then, later on within a FSM I have a state which compares a value to `byte_index`:

```
if byte_index < 8 then...
```

The problem here is that I defined `byte_index` as going up to 7 which means a *3-bit register* but I want to compare it to a number that is in decimal 8 which needs a *4-bit register*. Because behavioral simulation ignores the specified range, this may go undetected in behavioral simulation but in synthesis, the integer is truncated to match the maximum decimal size you specified.

This caused my FSM to be stuck on this state because it was waiting for `byte_index` to be greater than 7 and as a result, synthesis eliminated the FSM.

Why did I make this mistake? Simply because I'm used to using one *less* than the maximum bit size I want (eg. I want 4 bits so that means I need something [0:3] not [0:4] ). so I wrote `range 0 to 7` when I should have written `range 0 to 8`.

NOTE: you can compare this to Nandland's UART example I linked in the question to get a sense of what this integer's role was (it is his `r_Bit_Index`) but be aware my code uses an integer which goes up to 8 and his uses an integer which goes up to 7.